# How handle multiples "allow: owner" rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I use: "aws-amplify": "^5.3.11",

I did a type with multiple allow:owner rules.

According to documentation (https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/tools/cli-legacy/auth-directive/#multiple-authorization-rules), this should work:

```
type Offer u/model u/auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner, ownerField: "utilisateurID" },
    { allow: owner, ownerField: "guests", operations: [read] }
]) { 
    utilisateurID: ID
    guests: [ID]
}
```

First I create an Offer, then I update it to add guests.

I verified that Guests IDs are yet presents in the guest field in the Offer table.

I want all my guests can only read the offer.

But when I query:

```
        const { data } = await API.graphql({
            query: queries.getOffer,
            variables: { id },
            authMode: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS'
        })
```

It works for the UtilisateurID's owner,

But for guests I get a "Not Authorized to access getOffer on type Query" error :(

What could go wrong ?